# PPA keeps coming back while trying to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, ppa

I've tried using ppa-purge to get rid of it, said it was successful, removed it in the software & updates/Other software tab in the GUI, but then when I try to upgrade, it says:

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

> This was likely caused by:
>
> - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>   Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
>   package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
>   try the upgrade again.

> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Then when I check the Software & Updates GUI, it's back. How do I fix this?

Output when running apt-get update is:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                            
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_17.x focal InRelease                                     
Hit:4 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                                           
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                      
Hit:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release      
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Tried commenting out every file that contains sources.list in /etc/apt

Now I'm getting just a general error with no indication of how to fix.

> Could not calculate the upgrade An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Bug Report Filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1990163

Output from running "sudo apt upgrade":

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libc-ares2 libfdk-aac1 libfwupdplugin1 libjs-inherits
  libjs-is-typedarray libjs-psl libjs-typedarray-to-buffer libpython2-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libssl-dev libuv1-dev
  libxcb-composite0 node-abbrev node-ajv node-ansi node-ansi-align
  node-ansi-regex node-ansi-styles node-ansistyles node-aproba node-archy
  node-are-we-there-yet node-asap node-asn1 node-assert-plus node-asynckit
  node-aws-sign2 node-aws4 node-balanced-match node-bcrypt-pbkdf node-bl
  node-bluebird node-boxen node-brace-expansion node-builtins node-cacache
  node-call-limit node-camelcase node-caseless node-chalk node-chownr
  node-ci-info node-cli-boxes node-cliui node-clone node-co node-color-convert
  node-color-name node-colors node-columnify node-combined-stream
  node-concat-map node-concat-stream node-config-chain node-configstore
  node-console-control-strings node-copy-concurrently node-core-util-is
  node-cross-spawn node-crypto-random-string node-cyclist node-dashdash
  node-debug node-decamelize node-decompress-response node-deep-extend
  node-defaults node-define-properties node-delayed-stream node-delegates
  node-detect-indent node-detect-newline node-dot-prop node-duplexer3
  node-duplexify node-ecc-jsbn node-editor node-encoding node-end-of-stream
  node-err-code node-errno node-es6-promise node-escape-string-regexp
  node-execa node-extend node-extsprintf node-fast-deep-equal node-find-up
  node-flush-write-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-from2
  node-fs-vacuum node-fs-write-stream-atomic node-fs.realpath
  node-function-bind node-gauge node-genfun node-get-caller-file
  node-get-stream node-getpass node-glob node-got node-graceful-fs
  node-har-schema node-har-validator node-has-flag node-has-symbol-support-x
  node-has-to-string-tag-x node-has-unicode node-hosted-git-info
  node-http-signature node-iconv-lite node-iferr node-import-lazy
  node-imurmurhash node-inflight node-inherits node-ini node-invert-kv node-ip
  node-ip-regex node-is-npm node-is-obj node-is-object node-is-path-inside
  node-is-plain-obj node-is-retry-allowed node-is-stream node-is-typedarray
  node-isarray node-isexe node-isstream node-isurl node-jsbn
  node-json-parse-better-errors node-json-schema node-json-schema-traverse
  node-json-stable-stringify node-json-stringify-safe node-jsonify
  node-jsonparse node-jsonstream node-jsprim node-latest-version
  node-lazy-property node-lcid node-libnpx node-locate-path node-lockfile
  node-lodash node-lodash-packages node-lowercase-keys node-lru-cache
  node-make-dir node-mem node-mime node-mime-types node-mimic-fn
  node-mimic-response node-minimatch node-minimist node-mississippi
  node-mkdirp node-move-concurrently node-ms node-mute-stream node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npm-bundled node-npm-package-arg
  node-npm-run-path node-npmlog node-number-is-nan node-oauth-sign
  node-object-assign node-once node-opener node-os-locale node-os-tmpdir
  node-osenv node-p-cancelable node-p-finally node-p-is-promise node-p-limit
  node-p-locate node-p-timeout node-package-json node-parallel-transform
  node-path-exists node-path-is-absolute node-path-is-inside
  node-performance-now node-pify node-prepend-http node-process-nextick-args
  node-promise-inflight node-promise-retry node-promzard node-proto-list
  node-prr node-pseudomap node-psl node-pump node-pumpify node-punycode
  node-qs node-qw node-rc node-read node-read-package-json
  node-readable-stream node-registry-auth-token node-registry-url node-request
  node-require-directory node-require-main-filename node-resolve
  node-resolve-from node-retry node-rimraf node-run-queue node-safe-buffer
  node-semver node-semver-diff node-set-blocking node-sha node-shebang-command
  node-shebang-regex node-signal-exit node-slash node-slide node-sorted-object
  node-spdx-correct node-spdx-exceptions node-spdx-expression-parse
  node-spdx-license-ids node-sshpk node-ssri node-stream-each
  node-stream-iterate node-stream-shift node-strict-uri-encode
  node-string-decoder node-string-width node-strip-ansi node-strip-eof
  node-strip-json-comments node-supports-color node-tar node-term-size
  node-text-table node-through node-through2 node-timed-out node-tough-cookie
  node-tunnel-agent node-tweetnacl node-typedarray node-typedarray-to-buffer
  node-uid-number node-unique-filename node-unique-string node-unpipe
  node-uri-js node-url-parse-lax node-url-to-options node-util-deprecate
  node-uuid node-validate-npm-package-license node-validate-npm-package-name
  node-verror node-wcwidth.js node-which node-which-module node-wide-align
  node-widest-line node-wrap-ansi node-wrappy node-write-file-atomic
  node-xdg-basedir node-xtend node-y18n node-yallist node-yargs
  node-yargs-parser python-pkg-resources python2 python2-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Can you post output of `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any other `.list` files in that directory or its subdirectories

Comment: @Nmath I went in and commented out every source in that directory. Now I'm still getting:

Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

Comment: I just reverted back to previous snapshot. @Liso post body updated with apt-get update output

Comment: ...and what do the logs say?  You can't comment out *every* source.  Just comment out the PPAs and any other sources that are not official Ubuntu sources.

Comment: @Nmath Yeah that's what I meant. There were some in there for heroku, mongodb, and node that I commented out. You can see the logs in the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1990163

Comment: When was the last time you brought your system up-to-date without incident?  Can you post the output of `sudo apt upgrade` as well

Comment: @Nmath Output for sudo apt upgrade is in the post body. And this system is a virtual machine. I created it using version 20.04, and this is my first time trying to upgrade to 22.04. Haven't had any issues other than this.

Comment: Run `sudo apt autoremove`. Disable ALL non-Ubuntu sources. Backup your data. Then try the release-upgrade again. If the release-upgrade is successful, then you can re-enable your non-Ubuntu sources (with appropriate modification reflecting the new release, of course).

Comment: @user535733 running the auto remove seems to have worked lol. Thank you

Comment: Yes, a release upgrade requires the package manager to be able to bring the system up-to-date without any issues. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo apt autoremove` seems to have fixed it.